# Could not install package xxx due to compatibility issues with .NETFramework

Tags: c#, nuget-package

More specific , i am trying to download a nugget package named "PushBulletSharp 3.1.0" 
and keep receiving the following :

> Could not install package 'PushBulletSharp 3.1.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have not the permission to upgrade/change my project's NETFramework version , so i have tried everything else that i have found .

I have changed source package folder, config files , all the package versions , i have also tried to install it locally but still nothing . Any ideas ?

I am using the following :

- .NETFramework,Version=v4.0
- VS 2015
- Windows 10

Comment: Well, you're a bit stuck. The package requires a later version of the .Net framework, but you say you can't change it. You could try older versions of the package, but it's not very likely you'll find one that supports a version of the framework released 8 years ago.

Comment: If its one way , i will have to discuss with the customer if its possible to change the version or the package , if i have an alternative way , i would be grateful to follow it

Comment: You could try compiling the code yourself to target .Net 4.0

Comment: If you mean to build the package's solution with my current .Net , i have done it already . But i am not sure if i did the right steps after that .

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can build it as a DLL and reference that, or just add the source code to your solution.

Comment: OK , could you be more specific about these steps for both ways? I believe that i haven't something done while proceeding at these steps

Comment: In simple terms: 1) download code, build in .Net 4, copy output to a shared folder, then reference the binaries in that folder from your solution or 2) download code, add the projects you want to your solution. Make sure you include any dependencies.

Comment: Add the PushBulletSharp project to your solution as an existing project. Right click over the original projects `References` -> `Add reference` the select it from `Solution` in the tab menu to the left.

Comment: I have build and pasted the references to a folder within the solution folder , and i pasted them also at the package folder of the solution .  I imported them from my visual studio trying both paths . After that ? its supposed that i am ok ? or do i have to redownload the package ?